# Can someone please tell me how to remove or hide this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to add an event tracker on my site but I messed it up now I have this showing instead. Please how do I hide or remove? I installed the script through Google Tag Manager. I have removed the tag from Google Tag Manager but the script is still showing in footer.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you did not put the code between a script tag.

Comment: It seems so. Please what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a right click on the page and open the Chrome Developer Tools. At the tab Network you can check disable cache and reload your page. So it should be gone.

Do you have something like this in your Code?

```js
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

You should remove this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I still was able to remove the script. Could you please guide

Comment: It didn't work when I clicked on disabled. Is there a way to remove is completely.

Comment: Yes I do. I installed imthe sxri through Google tag manager. Thanks let me remove it.

Comment: Please where can I find this code? My site is running on a child theme so there are no codes on it.

Comment: if you mean the code above. Here you can find some help: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart

Comment: I deleted the Google tag manager code from the plugin I installed it with like you said and it removed the script it. I'm so grateful. Thanks a lot.